# Samsung KNOX is not working

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung, samsung-knox

I'm having a problem with my Samsung Galaxy S4 GT - I9500, it isn't rooted and has the official Lollipop ROM.

Whenever I open KNOX and select `setup` and press next, it closes and displays the error:  `Failed to start KNOX mode, Try Again`

Things I've tried so far:

1. Resetting App preferences.
2. Booting into Safe Mode and trying to run in Safe Mode.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Download Mode :

[image]

And Here's detail of my KNOX version :

[image]

Comment: Could you boot to download mode and post a picture of the information it gives? thanks

Comment: @SuperThomasLab - I've added the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you flash your phone with ODIN then your KNOX flag will **ALWAYS** be triggered. Even if you flash an **official** ROM/firmware package. As you can see in download mode: KNOX WARRANTY VOID: 1. That can never, yes I say **NEVER** be reset back to '0'. So you haven't got any warranty anymore on your phone and you can never use Knox anymore.  Hope my answer helped you to understand the issue.

Comment: I've installed Ozcan ROM in my phone before, which was custom ROM. It also downloaded KNOX and it worked totally fine. I've also read various documents and forum, but none of them says that you can't use KNOX if you're counter is triggered.

Comment: @Pankaj and how did you install the stock ROM again? If you did it with Odin then your flag will be triggered.

Comment: Yes, I did it through odin.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab, I suggested an edit to alter the last sentence in your answer because if I may say so, that sounds sarcastic.

Comment: @ThomasVos facing strange issue have posted it on stackexchange https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196585/secure-folder-password-input-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have rooted your phone. In that case KNOX Will refuse to work as it says:

KNOX warranty void:1

Sometimes this gets even triggered by normal OTA.

Comment: my phone isin't rooted now. As the system status displays "official", it should be working. Here's more detail : KNOX Counter is to help Samsung After-sale Service get a better idea of a device and see if users have tampered with the device when it comes to warranty claims. And reportedly, this newly developed KNOX Security technology prevents its KNOX Counter from being reset.

Comment: No, once the KNOX flag is triggered its triggered. It will refuse to work.

Comment: Could you please provide me any page or document providing support to your answer.

Comment: Just seen this a few minutes ago, fir more infirmation just search there http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2738175

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting. For installing a custom rom you need to root your phone. This DEFINETLY triggers KNOX. As KNOX detects a security issue (rooting is a security issue to KNOX) it WILL refuse to work.

Comment: @TechMod, there are ways to root your system without triggering Knox. See this: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115526/why-i-should-i-care-about-knox-warranty-can-i-still-root-my-s5 . Also, your answer does not describe why Knox doesn't work. Please put more effort into your answers from now on.